# Dissolve taking a really long time ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, performance, dissolve

I'm having an issue running several dissolves in both Arcgis 10.1 and Python 2.7.2, and 10.2.2 and Python 2.7.5 using arcpy.Dissolve_management (I'm working on 2 virtual machines). In both cases the dissolves are taking an extremely long time, sometimes multiple days. They do work eventually, but as I have several to do, I can't afford to wait days in between each run. I have 16GBs of RAM on each machine and I'm using x64 background processing. I thought it was file size at first, as some of my files are quite large, but I'm finding the same issue with files with as few as 100 features. I've tried Repair Geometry first, and I've made sure background geoprocessing is turned off. The files are in a file geodatabase.

Comment: Obvious question, what is your data? A few points or massively multi-part? An image would be good?

Comment: When you write that you are running several dissolves, does that mean that you have several feature classes that you need to dissolve?  Or that you are running the dissolve multiple times?

Comment: Does your fgdb need to be Compacted? Also, an Attribute Index for the fields included in Dissolve will help speed up the processing time.

Comment: @Hornbydd the data is river networks. It's mutli-part. Within the table I have name, Strahler value and length. I'm trying to dissolve based on name. Thank you!!

Comment: @mmoore I have several feature classes to dissolve from different watersheds. Thanks!!

Comment: Just an observation but dissolving by name may not be the best way. You can have rivers with the same name in different catchments...

Comment: Did you try dropping the spatial index before running the dissolve, then re-creating it afterwards? Perhaps arcgis is try to rebuild the spatial index of each feature as it writes them.  If each feature has a lot of vertices and a large extent, the resulting spatial index is likely very large.  That also illustrates a good reason NOT to combine features - the display performance will degrade since there are so many overlapping [MBRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle) for things like rivers.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to keep revising/improving your question to make what you are asking clearer to any potential answerers who may be reading it (but not have time to read the comments).